# Determine whether the equation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the function $F: P_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $F(p(t))=(p(2), p'(1))$, where $p(t)$ is an arbitrary linear polynomial of $t$.

Determine if the function is an isomorphism.

How do I go about this when $p(t$) is an arbitrary element of $P_1$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You need to show that $F$ is injective. That is, its kernel is zero. To do that, write $p(t)=at+b$. Then:

$F(p(t))=F(at+b)=0\iff (2a+b,a)=0.$ Is $a=b=0$ the only solution?

Also you need to show $F$ is surjective (well, this is not necessary because it is injective and both spaces have the same finite dimension. But probably you are asked to show it). Given $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,$ do there exist a solution of $(2a+b,a)=(x,y)$ for $a,b?$